# Intermittent Error 0x800A03EC when Application.Visible is false

Tags: c#, excel, com, excel-interop

I'm working with Excel interop in C#, and I've come across a strange error that I can't figure out. I've been doing a lot of reading on this error, and you may notice that the title of this post is very similar to [Intermittent HRESULT: 0x800A03EC errors during Excel SaveAs in .NET 2.0 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836610/intermittent-hresult-0x800a03ec-errors-during-excel-saveas-in-net-2-0-app). This question is not the same. The errors I have are intermittent, **but** there's some method to the madness. I just can't figure out what that method is.

I get the error `0x800A03EC` when I try to execute a line such as this one, which happens to occur right after I save a copy to the network:

```
someExcelWorksheet.getRange("MyNamedRange").Value = "new value";
```

I know that this is an obnoxious error and its causes are hard to narrow down. This is a comment from Hans Passant on the question linked in the first paragraph.

> It happens when Excel gets sulky about being too busy trying to get other stuff done. Could happen when you have a faster machine, allowing you to slam Excel harder. Difficult to deal with.

Here's the interesting part: it only happens when the Excel app is **not** visible **and** when I'm on **Wi-Fi**. Here are four use cases for clarification:

1. **100% success:** Ethernet (~90 down, ~40 up) + `app.Visible =  true;`
2. **100% success:** Ethernet (~90 down, ~40 up) + `app.Visible = false;`
3. **100% success:** Wi-Fi (~15 down, ~5 up) + `app.Visible = true;`
4. **30% success:** Wi-Fi (~15 down, ~5 up) + `app.Visible = false;`

I'm not necessarily looking for a solution to the `0x800A03EC` error, given that I have a way to make the app work already. I think I understand why there's an inconsistency between Wi-Fi and Ethernet, even on the same network. I believe it's simply a speed issue. The Excel files I'm accessing in the application are stored on the network, so it takes some time to access them. During that time, I think Excel is just going haywire. Irritating, but at least there's some potential explanation.

On the contrary, I can't figure out why the visibility property should affect whether or not the program executes correctly. This is an internal user-facing application that takes between ten and twenty minutes to run, and it would be ideal if it could run in the background, as hundreds of Excel spreadsheets flashing open and and then closing makes the user's machine pretty much unusable during the time that the application runs. However, it's not going to be run very frequently, so it's a disadvantage that can be accepted if it's required for the app to work.

My question then is: **Why does making the app visible prevent 0x800A03EC?**