# InteropServices.COMException (0x800A1066): Command failed under Teamcity

Tags: c#, teamcity, office-interop, windows-server-2012, office-2013

I have the following code in C# 4.5. It just writes a simple `Hello world` into a word document using Office 2013.

```
_Application word = new Application();
word.Visible = false;
_Document document = word.Documents.Add();
var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.docx");

try
{
    document.Words.First.InsertBefore("Hello World");
    document.SaveAs(file);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    logger.Fatal(e);
}
finally
{
    if (document != null)
    {
        document.Close();
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(document);
    }
    application.Quit();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(application);
}
```

It runs without any problems under Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012 R2. But when I launch it under Teamcity, on the same Windows Server 2012 R2, I expect the following errors :

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A1066): Command failed
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.SaveAs(Object& FileName, Object& FileFormat, Object& LockComments, Object& Password, Object& AddToRecentFiles, Object& WritePassword, Object& ReadOnlyRecommended, Object& EmbedTrueTypeFonts, Object& SaveNativePictureFormat, Object& SaveFormsData, Object& SaveAsAOCELetter, Object& Encoding, Object& InsertLineBreaks, Object& AllowSubstitutions, Object& LineEnding, Object& AddBiDiMarks)
   at Interop.HelloWorld.HelloWord.<>c__DisplayClass4.<WriteIt>b__3() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\27b855ae6e536c44\Interop\HelloWorld\HelloWord.cs:line 58
   at Interop.HelloWorld.HelloWord.WithDocument(_Application application, _Document document, Action handler) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\27b855ae6e536c44\Interop\HelloWorld\HelloWord.cs:line 72

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A1066): Command failed
  at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.Close(Object& SaveChanges, Object& OriginalFormat, Object& RouteDocument)
  at Interop.HelloWorld.HelloWord.WithDocument(_Application application, _Document document, Action handler) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\27b855ae6e536c44\Interop\HelloWorld\HelloWord.cs:line 92
  at Interop.HelloWorld.HelloWord.WriteIt(String file) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\27b855ae6e536c44\Interop\HelloWorld\HelloWord.cs:line 52
  at Interop.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\27b855ae6e536c44\Interop\Program.cs:line 25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem :

- Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408336/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x800a03ec). ie : Create `Desktop` folder under `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile` or `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile` (depending your OS)
- Check the configuration of office component with `dcomcnfg.exe` and change the identity into the properties to `The interactive user`.

Beware components names differ...

- Word : `Document Microsoft Word 97-2003`
- Excel : `Microsoft Excel Application`

You can retrieve registered components with `regedit` on `HKCR\AppId`. All Office 2013 components finish by `0000-0000-C000-000000000046`

Comment: Hmya, don't do that, hacking the System account profile is never a correct solution.  Document your question properly and show what the *file* variable contains.  And fix your problem by using a full path name.

Comment: TC is not running with System account, it has its own user. The file variable contains : `Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.docx");` I also tried with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`