# Workbooks.Open method throwing HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: excel, office-interop, excel-interop, office-2013

I am opening an excel file using

```
 object missing = Type.Missing;

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFilePath, missing, false, missing, missing, missing,
true, missing, missing, missing, missing, true, missing, missing, missing);
```

and it throws `HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`

It was working fine with office 2010 but after updating office libraries to version 15 and when deployed to server which had office 2013. I started getting this message.
I have also tried giving permission to Excel Object in DomConfig but it didn't worked,,

Comment: @adil-waqal: What version of server are you using? This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4448781/848737) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

note that there are many versions of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` 
 for me, I can find one in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14
```

and another one in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12
```

remove references from your project and add the suitable ones, rebuild your solution.
**EDIT #1**  
Office11 is the internal name for Office 2003. 
Office12 that for Office 2007.
Office14 that for Office 2010. 
When Installing Microsoft Office, make sure that the **.NET Programmability Support** feature is selected. Also, you can download them form : 
 [Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508) 
 try to find those for Office 2013 .

Comment: I couldnt find any office 14 folder but there are Office11 and Office12.. does it mean that i don't have PIA's for office 2013...?

Comment: @AdilWaqar : I modified the answer, please see : EDIT #1 .

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what version of Office PIAs you are using at the moment because even with old PIAs your code should work against the newest Office versions.

Instead, take a look a look at the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article which states the following:

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**